# UITableViewCell content moving around

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an iPhone app in which I'm using a UITableView to format a set of text responses, one per row. I've set up the cell in the storyboard to have a label inside it, and set up a constraint saying that the label should be 10 points from the edge of the cell. I then set up a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell`, set the cell in the storyboard to be of that class, and connected the outlet.

However, when I load the table, I see the text in the cell moving slightly to the right under some circumstances: when I select the cell, or when I load additional cells into the table. In fact, in the latter case, sometimes everything gets shifted to the right, even cells which were already there!

What the heck is going on here? The only changes I'm making in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` are to the text in the label, and I'm always setting it. And I've unset "Indent While Editing" on the cell in the storyboard.

Answering some of the questions: I'm setting the view up using the storyboard. Xcode isn't reporting any ambiguity with the constraints. Also, here are the screenshots, before and after:

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you please show us some code.. esp the part where you are setting your nsconstraint (are you setting it programmatically or via storyboard?)

Comment: can you also put some screenshots of what the cell looks like before moving and after moving?

Comment: Would it be possible to you to separate the problematic view and view controller, put it into new project and share its source?

Comment: @dpassage can you show the code of your customCell and also how you make the cell into the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: Agreed, we need to see the code in your "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method.  Maybe there is something different happening when the app reuses an existing table cell, vs. creating a new table cell?

Comment: Did you override `-layoutSubviews` in your cell? Did you remember to call `[ super layoutSubviews ]`? Also, put your content in `cell.contentView` not the cell itself.

Comment: (also your back button is in the wrong place.)

Comment: Learn to do the whole thing programmatically so that you actually KNOW what is going on in your code?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the constraints for the label are ambiguous. Ambiguity can make UI components jump around for inexplicable reasons. You probably need to set more constraints for the label to define its position on both axes.

Or, maybe all you need to do is set the label to the "size that fits content" (intrinsic content size) under the Editor menu in IB.

Comment: Xcode isn't reporting any ambiguous constraints, nor am I getting any log messages relating to constraints, so that may not be it. Setting the label to intrinsic content size doesn't seem like it makes sense, since each row in the table will have different text in the label.

Comment: Xcode doesn't report ambiguous constraints automatically. You have to call hasAmbiguousLayout on your view.

Comment: When a label is set to its intrinsic content size, it automatically adjusts its size according to the size of its content, i.e., its text.

Comment: Bilobatum, I don't want the label to change size. The whole problem I'm having is that it's moving around.

Comment: OK, I added code that traverses each cell in the table looking for labels for which `hasAmbiguousLayout` is true. There are none.

Comment: I guess I led you down the wrong path. Sorry. Do you want me to delete my answer, since it doesn't help?

Comment: It was still useful to rule something out, even if I still don't know what's going on. So let's leave it for now.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add a new label to the UITableViewCell, or are you working with the textLabel that already exists in it?  If you added a new one, consider removing it and using the cell's existing textLabel property instead.  If that's not an option for some reason, double-check that the label you've added is in the contentView of the cell, and that all the constraints are relative to the parent view, not to the cell itself.

Also, for debugging, you could set the cell's contentView background color to red (cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];) - this might give you a better sense of what's moving, the label or the whole view.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess without seeing your code.  I had a similar problem once, when the app reused an existing cell, the dimensions of the label were not correct.  So, I had to remove the old label in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method, before adding a new label.  Here's how I removed the old one:

```
UIView *oldLabel = [cell viewWithTag:3];
if (oldLabel != nil)
{
    [oldLabel removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Then I added a new label like this:

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:newLabelOrWhatever];
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth checking to see that your string content doesn't have a space prefixed on it.  Also, you could verify the actual position of the label by setting the background color.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when the label would move when the cell was selected. It was a custom cell that I was loading from a custom Nib.

In the Nib I had not set the backgroundView of the UITableViewCell (superclass) to any view. Once I set it (I set it to the ContentView) the issue stopped.

My auto-layout constrains seems fine and had no issues, so I'm assuming it was the above that fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell`, try implementing `layoutSubviews`. Let me try from the top of my head:

```
static CGFloat const kLeftMargin = 10.0f;

- (void) layoutSubviews
{
  [super layoutSubviews];

  /* Prepare for processing */
  CGSize cellSize = self.bounds.size;

  /* Change the textLabel frame */
  {
    /* Compute the new label frame */
    CGSize labelSize = self.textLabel.bounds.size;
    CGFloat xCoor = kLeftMargin;
    CGFloat yCoor = roundf((cellSize.height - labelSize.height) / 2.0f);
    CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(xCoor, yCoor,
                                   labelSize.width, labelSize.height);

    /* Set the new label frame */
    self.textLabel.frame = labelFrame;
  }
}
```

Now, this isn't what is usually recommended (since a lot of people use Storyboards and NIBs), but from experience, if you want some correct layouting done, implement `layoutSubviews`.